# Back Pain after workout and Remedies

Tags: exercise, pain, back-pain

Why does back pain hurt after doing exercises that has nothing to do with back , line bicep curl etc.? Can I strengthen my lower back to avoid this pain ?

Comment: I'd recommend you get a real strength training program to strengthen your body and ditch the curls. Starting Strength and Strong Lifts 5x5 are worth looking into. You will be strong and ultimately have larger biceps in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back pain whether it's upper back pain or low back pain frequently is caused by weak abdominal muscles. Since your abs are the front anchor of your spine, if they are weak, then the other structures supporting your spine (your back muscles, for example) will have to work harder. By developing stronger core muscles, you'll be less likely to injure or strain your back muscles.

Core strengthening is more than just achieving six-pack abs. Developing strong abdominal muscles may actually help prevent back pain by making you less prone to back injuries and teaching you proper spinal alignment.

> **The Significance of Core Strength**

If you think about it, your core is in the center of your body. It needs to be strong to support the weight of your entire body, including your back and neck. Adding core strengthening to your exercise routine can help protect your back and neck. By boosting your core strength, you'll also be less likely to rely on other back pain treatments, such as medications.

It's important to incorporate exercises that work all of your abdominal muscles equally. Core exercises should involve the major muscles in your abdomen, including your internal and external obliques and the transverse abdominals.

> **Core Strengthening Exercises for Back Pain: Prehab**

Below are some exercises that can help you develop strong abs and prevent back pain.

- Front Pillar Bridge
- Lateral Pillar Bridge
- Glute Bridge
- Hand Walking
- Half-Kneeling Chop
- Half-Kneeling Lift

> **Movement Prep**

Incorporate these movement prep exercises into your warm-up routine:

- Quadruped Posterior Rocking
- Foam Roll (but not directly on the area of a strained muscle)
- Quadruped Opposites

---

***You should consult your physician or other health care professional before starting this or any other fitness program.***

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20581648

---

***Response:***

Valsalva maneuver was not mentioned in my post.

First important concepts to understand.

- Global muscles **produce** movement.
- Local muscles **prevent** movement.

Failure to stabilize the spine isn't ONLY due to weakness. Altered neuromuscular firing patterns produce the same result.

If you're more powerful global muscles are firing before your deep stabilizers this results in large force being applied to an unstablized spinal column.
This is why the trA is so important. It is activated first before movement in any direction.  Unlike your quadratus lumborum which is only active during sagittal plane movements.

**Directly from a Systematic Review:**

When rehabilitating a patient with low back dysfunction, low-load isometric motor control exercises for the TA and multifidi should be emphasized. The drawing-in maneuver should be performed with each exercise to elicit TA and multifidi contraction without activating global muscles. Rehabilitation of the local muscles with specific motor control exercises is necessary to enhance stability while protecting the spine from excessive loads during the rehabilitation program.

> The local muscles promote segmental stabilization. Inclusion of global
>   muscles too early may be deleterious during the rehabilitation
>   program.  Local muscles are superior to global muscles in controlling
>   shear loads; unnecessary activation of global muscles may impose
>   excessive compressive loads to the spine. Activation of global muscles
>   in the presence of dysfunction may actually increase the challenge on
>   the local muscles to provide segmental stability.

---

**Sources:**
Richardson C. Therapeutic Exercise for Spinal Segmental Stabilization in Low Back Pain: Scientific Basis and Clinical Approach. New York, NY: Churchill Livingstone

Please read these studies (download the PDF free).
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3806181/#bibr2-1941738113502451
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10617782_Core_stability_exercise_in_chronic_low_back_pain

Comment: I assume that you are not advocating use of the Valsalva maneuver, without which it's unclear how stronger spinal _flexors_ (the anterior abdominal muscles) can compensate for relatively-weak spinal _extensors_.  Please explain.

Comment: Valsalva is normal. If you were to help push a car, you'd hold your breath on the first push.

Comment: @EricKaufman, I agree that the Valsalva maneuver is normal.  It helps keep the spine same and transmit force more efficiently.  Without the large held breath in the Valsalva, contracting abdominal muscles will tend to flex the spine, but this answer seems to be recommending doing so to support the spine... the mechanism of which is unclear to me.

Comment: I do have week abs, actually i dont do any abs excercise

Comment: @CCCV A stiffer thoracic cavity and tighten diaphragm provides anterior rigidity (across a frontal/coronal plane) when the thoracic and to some extent cervical spine tries to roll forward/anterior/down/inferior. More plainly, for the same reason a tightened erector spinae provides bracing of the spine so does tighten anatomy in the front.

Comment: @EricKaufman - Exactly!

Comment: @EricKaufman: I think all of what you said is true _only if_ combined with a held breath. Otherwise, contracting anterior musculature will tend to flex the spine, possibly exacerbating OP's LBP.  Regardless, I maintain that appropriate barbell strength training, including deadlifts, would strengthen OP's back more than this answer's suggestions, and probably relieve the pain.

Comment: The valsalva implies a held breath; you're exhaling against a closed glottis.

Comment: @EricKaufman, right.  I just didn't see anything about Valsalva in this answer, which seems to just advocate "stronger core".  Regardless, I think I was wrong earlier: Stronger anterior abdominal muscles _do_ seem to help stabilize the torso to some extent, even without Valsalva.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be specific, like which part does it hurt. If its the back muscle after a bicep curl it might be because of bad posture during exercise or might be cause you are moving your body during the point of fatigue of the bicep curl.

if it lasts more than two days, you better take a day or two off , or avoid working that muscle group.
some useful tips [Here](http://www.prevention.com/fitness/fitness-tips/relieve-back-pain-with-these-workout-tips) and [Here](http://www.mensfitness.com/training/pro-tips/trainer-qa-why-my-lower-back-sore)

Comment: I am sure it is due to bad posture during training, point is how to avoid that pain without changing posture

Answer (score 0):

If your back hurts after performing movements (such as a standing bicep curl) in which your spine is (or should be) vertical and rigid, then you probably are not actually keeping your spine vertical and rigid.

Consider doing the following:

1. Having someone watch your exercises, especially for any spinal flexion.
2. Strengthening your back with properly-programmed and meticulously-executed low-bar back squats and deadlifts.

Comment: #1 I agree with.  #2 is literally dangerous. It essentially the same as if someone posted regarding shoulder pain and recommending shoulder presses (contraction of the painful muscle).  In addition low back injuries are frequently caused due to an improper hip-hinge during deadlifts.

Comment: @Mike-DHSc, _incorrectly-performed_ and/or _incorrectly-programmed_ (e.g., too many) deadlifts can be detrimental, but I *did* say "properly-programmed and meticulously-executed ... deadlifts", which are *not* dangerous, but -- on the contrary -- help strengthen the spine and reduce pain.  The same is often true of _correct_ barbell overhead presses.

Comment: @Mike-DHSc, how do you recommend that someone strengthen their back (posterior chain)?

Comment: In a pain-free patient, your recommendations would be fine.  Since he is experiencing constant back pain and the cause is unknown - you’re looking at a ton of spinal pathology to rule out.  Chronic LBP is the literally the last injury you want (see Steve Kerr).

Comment: @Mike-DHSc, thanks for your thoughts.  FWIW, it sounds as though OP's LBP is not chronic, but acute, and closely follows certain exercises.